# Pyparsing Identifiers pushed onto the stack twice

Tags: python, stack, pyparsing

I'm not sure why this is happening, but my `ident` terminal gets pushed unto the stack twice. This doesn't happen with any other terminal in my grammar. All my save_xxx_function simply add a converted value to a `stack`. In the case of `save_ident_function`, I'm just adding the first token to the stack without any processing.

```
# Terminal symbols defined here....
ident = Word(alphas, alphanums + '_')

expr = Forward()
atom = Forward()
arg = expr
args = delimitedList(arg)

func_call = (ident + lbrace + Optional(args) + rbrace).setParseAction(save_token_function)

bracketed_list = (lbracket + Optional(delimitedList(atom)) +    rbracket).setParseAction(save_list_function)

atom << ( bracketed_list | func_call | (lbrace + expr.suppress() + rbrace)  |     decimal.setParseAction(save_decimal_function) | integer.setParseAction(save_int_function) | ident.setParseAction(save_ident_function) | sglQuotedString.setParseAction(save_string_function) )

factor = Forward()

factor << atom + ZeroOrMore( (exponent + factor).setParseAction(save_token_function) )

term = factor + ZeroOrMore( (multdivide + factor).setParseAction(save_token_function) )

rel_term = term + ZeroOrMore( (relational + term).setParseAction(save_token_function) )

expr << rel_term + ZeroOrMore( (plusminus + rel_term).setParseAction(save_token_function) )

# Define the grammar now ...
grammar = expr + StringEnd()

# function to just drop the identifier on to the stack
def save_ident_function(s, l, tokens):
token = tokens[0]
stack.append(token)
```

I get the following stack for the following expressions:
2 * 3 => [2, 3, '*']
x * 2 => ['x', 'x', 2, '*']

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the problem I had here was that I was re-using the `ident` terminal. I used the `ident` terminal for variables, but I also used it for the `func_call` (function call) non-terminal. I'm not sure if that's just bad practice overall to re-use terminals like that or if during the recognition process they call the parse action on a grammar rule.

The fix was simple... just use a different terminal for the `func_call` name.

```
ident = Word(alphas, alphanums + '_')
# Add a non-terminal for the name of a function
func_name = Word(alphas, alphanums + '_')

# Change func_call grammar rule to use func_name for the name instead of ident
func_call = (func_name + lbrace + Optional(args) + rbrace).setParseAction(save_token_function)
```

Additionally, `func_name` doesn't have a parse action, `func_call` does. That may have been complicating things as well.